# Understanding default access modifiers

Tags: c#, class

I am confused about access modifiers, so I thought I would ask a couple of quick questions for clarification:

Is it always the case that in the absence of access modifiers for data members of a class, the default is `private`, though the class itself is `internal`?

```
class A
{
    int x;
}
```

So, `int x` is `private int x` and `class A` is `internal class A`?

=========================================

Also, why would the following code not compile?

```
class A
{
    protected int x;
}

public class B : A
{}
```

Comment: methinks it pretty clear error message: _Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'A' is less accessible than class 'B'_

Comment: If `class A` member of `namespace`, then it is `internal`. If it member of other class, then it is `private`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) states, classes and structs are by default internal and their members are private.

The code won't compile because, as the error message will state, you cannot inherit from a less accessible class. In this case the child class would be public and the parent internal.